# Evaluate the trigonometric integral $2a^3\int_0^{2\pi}(1-2\cos(x)+\cos^2(x))\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int_0^{2\pi}a^2(1-\cos(x))^2\sqrt{((a-a\cos(x))^2+\sin^2(x))}\,dx$$
After some work I get
$$2a^3\int_0^{2\pi}(1-2\cos(x)+\cos^2(x))\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\,dx$$
And stopped:( Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Use the double-angle identity
$$\cos 2u = 2 \cos^2 u - 1,$$
(and set $u = \frac{x}{2}$) to express write of the trigonometric functions as functions the common argument $\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: I had transformed
$$(1-2cos(x)+cos^2(x))$$
to
$$(4-2cos^2(x/2)-2cos^2(x/2)sin^2(x/2))$$
but it didn't become easier

Comment: Where did $\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$ come from? After making the above substitution, one should have a single factor of $\sin \frac{x}{2}$ and a polynomial in $\cos \frac{x}{2}$, which suggests a particular solution...

Comment: Found mistake
$$1-2cos(x)+cos^2(x)$$
$$1-2(2cos^2(x/2)-1)+(2cos^2(x/2)-1)^2$$
$$1-4cos^2(x/2)-2+4cos^4(x/2)-4cos^2(x/2)+1$$
$$4cos^4(x/2)-8cos^2(x/2)$$
Sooo, I have
$$2a^3\int_0^{2\pi}(4cos^4(x/2)-8cos^2(x/2))\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\,dx$$
How should I work around with $cos^4$ ?

Comment: Again, the occurrence of $\sin u$ and $\cos u$ suggest a particular substitution.

Answer (score 0):

In your simplified form, try substituting $u=\cos\left(\frac x2\right)$